# Adding a Linear layer to my LSTM made the validation loss skyrocket in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

My model was:

```
    def forward(self, x, hidden=None):
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)

        lstm_out = (lstm_out[:, :, :self.hidden_size] +
                    lstm_out[:, :, self.hidden_size:])

        out = torch.nn.SELU()(lstm_out)
        return out, hidden
```

It now is:

```
    def forward(self, x, hidden=None):
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        batch_size = lstm_out.size(0)

        flattened_out = lstm_out.view(-1, self.hidden_size * 2)

        lstm_out = (lstm_out[:, :, :self.hidden_size] +
                    lstm_out[:, :, self.hidden_size:])
        out = self.linear(flattened_out)

        out = torch.nn.functional.relu(out)

        view_out = out.view(batch_size, self.seq_length, -1)

        return view_out, hidden
```

I used to get validation loss (with MSELoss) under `1000` after 2-3 epochs. Now with the Linear layer, it is skyrocketing up to `15000` even after 10 epochs. Why would this be?

Comment: Perhaps normalizing the outputs would help keep the loss under control. Lower learning rate should also work

Comment: My data is `log(1 + x)` normalized. So the values are within a pretty small range (0 - 4)

Comment: You're right about learning rate. That did it. If you post as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try lowering the learning rate :)